# When does Jackson require no-arg constructor for deserialization?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, lombok

In my spring boot project, I noticed a strange Jackson behavior. I searched over internet, found out what to do, but haven't found out **why**.

UserDto:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserDto {

    private String username;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private UserStatus status;

    private byte[] avatar;

    private ZonedDateTime created_at;
}
```

Adding a new user works just fine.

TagDto:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TagDto {

    private String tag;
}
```

Trying to add a new tag ends with an error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of TagDto (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

The solution to the problem was to add zero-arg constructor to the TagDto class.

Why does Jackson require no-arg constructor for deserialization in TagDto, while working just fine with UserDto?

Used same method for adding both.
My Tag and User entities are both annotated with

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
```

and have all args constructors:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User extends AbstractModel {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private UserStatus status;

    @Lob
    private byte[] avatar;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private ZonedDateTime created_at;

    public User(final String username, final String password, final String email, final String name, final String surname) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.created_at = ZonedDateTime.now();
    }
}

@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Tag extends AbstractModel {

    private String tag;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
public abstract class AbstractModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
}
```

Entity generation:

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@Valid @RequestBody final D dto) {
        this.abstractModelService.add(dto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    
    public void add(final D dto) {
    //CRUD repository save method
        this.modelRepositoryInterface.save(this.getModelFromDto(dto));
    }

    @Override
    protected Tag getModelFromDto(final TagDto tagDto) {
        return new Tag(tagDto.getTag());
    }

    @Override
    protected User getModelFromDto(final UserDto userDto) {
        return new User(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getPassword(), userDto.getEmail(), userDto.getName(), userDto.getSurname());
    }
```

Error occurs when parsing JSON

```
{"tag":"example"}
```

sent via postman localhost:8081/tag/add, returns

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-26T18:50:39.974+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/tag/add"
}
```

I am using Lombok v1.18.12 and Spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with Jackson v2.11.2.

Comment: Jackson won't use a constructor with arguments by default, you'd need to tell it to do so with the [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation. By default it tries to use the no-args constructor which isn't present in your class.

Comment: @Thomas How does UserDto work fine then?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm no Lombox expert so I'd have to guess but one reason might be that `TagDto` only has one property which might cause the problem. Sometimes those libraries have or cause bugs such as [this one](https://github.com/meltmedia/jackson-crypto/issues/6) so it might be good to provide more information on what versions you're using.

Comment: Thank you, added version info.

Comment: Can you add the full code? how do @Entity classes look like? how exactly you store either? Jackson might try to use AllArgsConstructor, when appropriate. It might be that Jackson uses all args for one entity, and no-args - for another. It depends on *how* do you instantiate those DTOs. Try to remove Lombok annotations and provide your own constructors. Then add some print statements in those, and see it yourself - which is called - when.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Thanks for your insights, added model classes code.

Comment: I still cannot see *HOW* you transform entities to DTOs, how you *add* them. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and tell us - when/where exactly you have an error? when you convert to DTO, most likely, right? Also, your `User` class is missing some part(s).

Comment: One more time: Please, show us, *how you transform* the Entity<->DTO. That's most likely in `getModelFromDto()`. Provide `abstractModelService.add(dto);` as well.. You're most likely converting DTO to Model as well. Also, it's important what you receive as a POST payload (what you then map to your DTO).

Comment: getModelFromDto() and abstractModelService.add(dto) method are provided. Transforming entity to dto is redundant in this question, as error occurs before doing anything with an actual entity

Comment: You can add `@AllArgsConstructor` and a `@NoArgsConstructor` simultaneously. Jackson seems to prefer a noargsconstructor by default. When I create value objects I commonly use the following annotations `@Data`, @AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgConstructor`, that works all the time....

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*TL;DR: Solution is at the end.*

Jackson supports multiple ways of creating POJOs. The following lists the most common ways, but it likely not a complete list:

1. Create instance using no-arg constructor, then call setter methods to assign property values.

   ```java
   public class Foo {
       private int id;

       public int getId() { return this.id; }

       @JsonProperty
       public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
   }
   ```

   Specifying [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) is optional, but can be used to fine-tune the mappings, together with annotations like [`@JsonIgnore`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html), [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html), ...
2. Create instance using constructor with arguments.

   ```java
   public class Foo {
       private int id;

       @JsonCreator
       public Foo(@JsonProperty("id") int id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return this.id;
       }
   }
   ```

   Specifying [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) for the constructor is optional, but I believe it is required if there is more than one constructor. Specifying `@JsonProperty` for the parameters is optional, but is required for naming the properties if the parameter names are not included in the class file (`-parameters` compiler option).

   The parameters imply that the properties are required. Optional properties can be set using setter methods.
3. Create instance using factory method.

   ```java
   public class Foo {
       private int id;

       @JsonCreator
       public static Foo create(@JsonProperty("id") int id) {
           return new Foo(id);
       }

       private Foo(int id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return this.id;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create instance from text value using `String` constructor.

   ```java
   public class Foo {
       private int id;

       @JsonCreator
       public Foo(String str) {
           this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
       }

       public int getId() {
           return this.id;
       }

       @JsonValue
       public String asJsonValue() {
           return Integer.toString(this.id);
       }
   }
   ```

   This is useful when a the POJO has a simply text representation, e.g. a `LocalDate` is a POJO with 3 properties (`year`, `month`, `dayOfMonth`), but is generally best serialized as a single string (`yyyy-MM-dd` format). [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) identifies the method to be used during serialization, and `@JsonCreator` identifies the constructor/factory-method to be used during deserialization.

   *Note:* This can also be used for single-value construction using JSON values other than `String`, but that is very rare.

Ok, that was the background information. What is happening for the examples in the question, it that `UserDto` works because there is only one constructor (so `@JsonCreator` is not needed), and many arguments (so `@JsonProperty` is not needed).

However, for `TagDto` there is only a *single-argument* constructor without any annotations, so Jackson classifies that constructor as a type #4 (from my list above), not a type #2.

Which means that it is expecting the POJO to be a value-class, where the JSON for the enclosing object would be `{ ..., "tag": "value", ... }`, not `{ ..., "tag": {"tag": "example"}, ... }`.

To resolve the issue, you need to tell Jackson that the constructor is a property initializing constructor (#2), not a value-type constructor (#4), by specifying `@JsonProperty` on the constructor argument.

This means that you cannot have Lombok create the constructor for you:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class TagDto {

    private String tag;

    public TagDto(@JsonProperty("tag") String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent explanation of not only the solution to the original question, but also enough background information to educate readers. The question that I'm left with is what to do in this situation where I don't control the classes being deserialized (so I can't add annotations)? I'll continue searching for the answer to that question.

Comment: "but I believe it is required if there is more than one constructor", it's not required if one of the constructors is a default constructor. It's probably required otherwise