# "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value - SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using SpringBoot with Mongo database and I am trying to save embedded documents into database.

I have this model:

**Profile.java**

```
@Data
@Document
public class Profile {

    public final City city;
    public final String imageId;

    public Profile(City city,
                   String imageId) {
        this.city = city;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile{" +
                ", city=" + city +
                ", imageId='" + imageId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    private static boolean atLeast(int numChars, String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }
        var str = s.strip();
        return str.length() >= numChars;
    }


    public static ProfileBuilder builder() {
        return new ProfileBuilder();
    }

    public static final class ProfileBuilder {
        public City city;
        public String imageId;

        private ProfileBuilder() {
        }


        public ProfileBuilder withCity(City city) {
            this.city = city;
            return this;
        }

        public ProfileBuilder withImageId(String imageId) {
            this.imageId = imageId;
            return this;
        }

        public Profile build(){
            return new Profile(city, imageId);
        }
    }
}
```

**City.java**

```
public class City {

    public final String name;

    public City(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City{" +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**ProfileController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Profile addUser(@RequestBody Profile profile) {
        return profileService.addProfile(profile);
    }
```

and with postman I am sending this JSON

```
{
 "city":{
   "name":"Atena"
  },
   "imageId" : "Doe",
  }
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `domain.City` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator);"
```

Comment: Please add the code of your REST Controller where you receive this JSON

Comment: I added it, you can take a look :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two solutions.

1. Add `@JsonCreator` to constructor and `@JsonProperty` to its arguments (to instruct Jackson how to substitute JSON items into constructor in proper order)

```
class Profile {
    ...
    @JsonCreator
    public Profile(@JsonProperty("city") City city, 
                   @JsonProperty("imageId") String imageId) {
        this.city = city;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    ...
}
```

*(+ same for City class)*

2. Un`final` class properties and provide default no-arg constructor (along with existing all-arg constructor).

```
class Profile {

    public City city;
    public String imageId;

    public Profile() {
    }

    public Profile(City city, String imageId) {
        this.city = city;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
}
```

*(+ same for City class)*

**Test**

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\"city\":{\"name\":\"Atena\"},\"imageId\":\"Doe\"}";
        Profile p = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Profile.class);
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Profile{, city=City{, name='Atena'}, imageId='Doe'}
```

Comment: I am having same error for first example you provided and for second it has to be final. So I have to find way of making it work with final

Comment: It works for me. I've updated my answer with unit test. PS: Make sure that you use valid JSON, because one that you've shown in your Question is invalid

Comment: Yes, I wrote test for it as well and it works fine, but when I am sending it with postman as JSON it's not working. Hmm maybe you are right my JSON is wrong. Can you please help with working one?

Comment: @user9347049 in my test snippet `{"city":{"name":"Atena"},"imageId":"Doe"}` is a valid JSON

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) it works now

Comment: @user9347049 you're welcome

Comment: Added only the no-arg constructor was enough for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In  classes with only one attribute, to deserialize an object Json need a nos argument constructor from that class.

In your class city you need a nos arg constructor add this to your class you need:

```
 public  City () {}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why no-argument constructor is required for classes with only one property, but not for classes with more than one field?

Even after reading this article(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080983/when-does-jackson-require-no-arg-constructor-for-deserialization), I still don't understand.