# Is this constructor change still Java Object Serialization compatible?

Tags: java, serialization

I couldn't figure out if this change in the constructor is still (de)serialization compatible in Java Object Serialization. These classes are used as http-session objects.

Current code

```
import com.foo.FooDataObject;

public class Foo extends FooBase {

  public Foo(final FooDataObject fooDataObject) {
    super(fooDataObject.getFoo);
  }
}

public abstract class FooBase implements Serializable {

  private final String foo;

  public FooBase(final String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Change (the class of the constructor parameter changed):

```
import com.foo.wherever.FooDO;

public class Foo extends FooBase {

  public Foo(final FooDO fooDO) {
    super(fooDO.getFoo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Under what serialization system? Java Object Serialization? Jackson? JSON? XML?

Comment: Java Object Serialization, I'll update my question.

Comment: Constructors of Serializable classes don't change Java Object Serialization compatibility other than by affecting the auto-generated `serialVersionUID`, which you shouldn't be relying on anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be. You are simply changing the type of the parameter, but still using the same way of instance construction - via constructor with arguments.

See more of the available ways for Jackson deserialization (if you use this framework) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64081932/11812518).

Comment: I'm using these classes as Http-Session objects if this matters. I updated my question.