# Quarkus Post Parameter unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, quarkus

I am currently writting a URL-Shortener. I have this post methhod to upload a Url pair (short and long url)

```
/**
     * Adds a new URL pair to the database.
     *
     * @return a message confirming the addition of the URL pair
     */
    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Transactional
    public String addURLPair(UrlEntity urlEntity) {
        shortUrlRepository.addURLPair(urlEntity);
        return "Short URL: " + urlEntity.getShortUrl() + ", Original URL: " + urlEntity.getOriginalUrl();
    }
```

this is my entity class

```
@Entity
public class UrlEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    /**
     * The shortend URL in Bas 62 Format
     */
    private String shortUrl;

    /**
     * The original URL, where the user gets relocated
     */
    private String originalUrl;
}
```

but when i want to call it in postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJiVB.png)

this unsupported Media Type Error occurs and i dont know why.

I tried to fix it by looking up but found nothing

Comment: Do you have `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` or `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` as dependency? --- The entity looks odd. Jackson normally needs a no-args constructor and setters, or an all-args constructor.

Comment: I use `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson`. Thanks for your tip with the no-args ctor. I applied it and now it works fine. Thank you

Comment: @Turing85 mind adding that as an answer? It will be a lot of easier for future readers

Answer (score 1):

First of, to de/serialize data from/to JSON, we need a library. There are two general providers in quarkus: JSON-B and Jackson. For resteasy - the jax-rs framework used by quarkus - both providers come in two flavours: reactive and non-reactive. Whether we should choose the classic or reactive variant depends on whether we use the classic or reactive resteasy variant. Thus, we have four dependencies to choose from:

JSON-B, classic:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

JSON-B, reactive:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Jackson, classic:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Jackson, reactive:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With this set up, we need to assure that the objects can be de/serialized. For jackson this means that the class to deserialize needs to either have a no-args constructor, a constructor with annotated parameters, or a creator-method with annotated parameters. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64080983/when-does-jackson-require-no-arg-constructor-for-deserialization) by [ayfkly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12351888/ayfkly) and its answers for details.

I also recommend reading the [`quarkus.io` documentation on creating JSON Rest web services](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json).